# Export a BCP file into CSV format

Tags: python, csv, bcp

I would like to extract data from 
[Data Charity Register Extract](http://data.charitycommission.gov.uk/default.aspx) and export it as an Excel file (.csv).

This person published in Github his code to do so by using an  [import.py file](https://github.com/ncvo/charity-commission-extract)

Here is how I did: in two ways:

The first way:

1. I download file: RegPlusExtract_November_2015.zip from the link above and put it in C:\Python27 (where I also install Python)
2. I open the code file below (import.py) and the one after (bcp.py) in IDLE and run import.py (using F5). I put these two .py files in C:\Python27

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bcp
import zipfile
import sys

cc_files = {
    "extract_acct_submit": [
      "regno",
      "submit_date",
      "arno",
      "fyend"
    ], 
    "extract_aoo_ref": [
      "aootype",
      "aookey",
      "aooname",
      "aoosort",
      "welsh",
      "master",
      "code"
    ], 
    "extract_ar_submit": [
      "regno",
      "arno",
      "submit_date"
    ], 
    "extract_charity": [
      "regno",
      "subno",
      "name",
      "orgtype",
      "gd",
      "aob",
      "aob_defined",
      "nhs",
      "ha_no",
      "corr",
      "add1",
      "add2",
      "add3",
      "add4",
      "add5",
      "postcode",
      "phone",
      "fax",
    ], 
    "extract_charity_aoo": [
      "regno",
      "aootype",
      "aookey",
      "welsh",
      "master"
    ], 
    "extract_class": [
      "regno",
      "class"
    ], 
    "extract_class_ref": [
      "classno",
      "classtext",
    ], 
    "extract_financial": [
      "regno",
      "fystart",
      "fyend",
      "income",
      "expend"
    ], 
    "extract_main_charity": [
      "regno",
      "coyno",
      "trustees",
      "fyend",
      "welsh",
      "incomedate",
      "income",
      "grouptype",
      "email",
      "web"
    ], 
    "extract_name": [
      "regno",
      "subno",
      "nameno",
      "name"
    ], 
    "extract_objects": [
      "regno",
      "subno",
      "seqno",
      "object"
    ], 
    "extract_partb": [
      "regno",
      "artype",
      "fystart",
      "fyend",
      "inc_leg",
      "inc_end",
      "inc_vol",
      "inc_fr",
      "inc_char",
      "inc_invest",
      "inc_other",
      "inc_total",
      "invest_gain",
      "asset_gain",
      "pension_gain",
      "exp_vol",
      "exp_trade",
      "exp_invest",
      "exp_grant",
      "exp_charble",
      "exp_gov",
      "exp_other",
      "exp_total",
      "exp_support",
      "exp_dep",
      "reserves",
      "asset_open",
      "asset_close",
      "fixed_assets",
      "open_assets",
      "invest_assets",
      "cash_assets",
      "current_assets",
      "credit_1",
      "credit_long",
      "pension_assets",
      "total_assets",
      "funds_end",
      "funds_restrict",
      "funds_unrestrict",
      "funds_total",
      "employees",
      "volunteers",
      "cons_acc",
      "charity_acc"
    ], 
    "extract_registration": [
      "regno",
      "subno",
      "regdate",
      "remdate",
      "remcode"
    ], 
    "extract_remove_ref": [
      "code",
      "text"
    ], 
    "extract_trustee": [
      "regno",
      "trustee"
    ]
}

def import_zip(zip_file):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r')
    print 'Opened zip file: %s' % zip_file
    for filename in cc_files:
        try:
            bcp_filename = filename + '.bcp'
            csv_filename = filename + '.csv'
            bcpdata = zf.read(bcp_filename)
            bcp.convert(bcpdata, csvfilename=csv_filename, col_headers=cc_files[filename])
            print 'Converted: %s' % bcp_filename
        except KeyError:
            print 'ERROR: Did not find %s in zip file' % bcp_filename

def main():
    zip_file = sys.argv[1]
    import_zip(zip_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import csv

def convert(bcpdata, csvfilename="", lineterminator='*@@*', delimiter='@**@', quote='"', newdelimiter=',', col_headers=None, escapechar='\\', newline='\n'):
    bcpdata = bcpdata.replace(escapechar, escapechar + escapechar)
    bcpdata = bcpdata.replace(quote, escapechar + quote)
    bcpdata = bcpdata.replace(delimiter, quote + newdelimiter + quote)
    bcpdata = bcpdata.replace(lineterminator, quote + newline + quote)
    if csvfilename=="":
        csvfilename = 'converted.csv'
    with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as csvfile:
        if(col_headers):
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(col_headers)
        csvfile.write('"')
        csvfile.write(bcpdata)
        csvfile.write('"')

def main():
    bcp_filename = sys.argv[1]
    try:
        csv_filename = sys.argv[2]
    except IndexError:
        csv_filename = bcp_filename.replace('.bcp', '.csv')
    with open(bcp_filename, 'rb') as bcpfile:
        bcpdata = bcpfile.read()
        convert(bcpdata, csv_filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It struck me with this error:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\bcp.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\bcp.py", line 21, in main
    bcp_filename = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\import.py", line 175, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\import.py", line 171, in main
    zip_file = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Can anyone please point out where it's gone wrong?

Second way:

Then I try to use Command Prompt in Windows to run the file: 
First I set path to where I save all files (C:\python27)
Then I run in command prompt

```
python import RegPlusExtract_November_2015.zip
```

It struck me with: error:

```
 File"<stdin>", line 1

python import RegPlusExtract_November_2015.zip
```

Please can anyone point out where I get it wrong or show me how to extract csv file from the data link above.

Comment: It looks like it wants the name of the file as a command-line argument, and you didn't provide it. Try `python import.py RegPlusExtract_February_2015.zip `.

Comment: Thanks very much, it gives me: File "<stdin>".line 1 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hi @pnuts: can you explain more? I don't get what rollback means here.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. Yes I meant CSV file. Yes. Thank you!

Comment: Please say what is the name of the input file (bcp format), and show how you lauch the script. Without that we won't be able to help you

Comment: Hi @SergeBallesta, As you suggested, I have edited my post to include more information. Many thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a script from IDLE, you cannot pass parameters in `sys.argv`. So in that use case the error is normal. But after the errors have shown up on F5, you should be able to directly call:

```
zip_file = 'RegPlusExtract_November_2015.zip'
import_zip(zip_file)
```

it should allow you to process your data.

For second way in command prompt, you must give the exact name of script file. The command should be:

```
python import.py RegPlusExtract_November_2015.zip
```

But anyway, it is *bad* to put your own scripts and other data files in Python directory. `C:\Python27` should only contain files from the initial Python distribution, and other general utilities, **not** you local scripts.
 The usual way is to add `c:\Python` to your PATH environment, and use a dedicated directory for your Data Charity processing

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I sound silly but what do you mean by "directly call"? Should I add it to the import file or type it in ISLE? I tried both and get this error: NameError: name 'import_zip' is not defined

Comment: However, the second way works. The script only works with Python 2.7 (I installed 3.5 too, and unistall it already). In the command, I put the pathway too (C:\python27\import/py ...) and finally it works, thank you!